# Livepatch not updating kernel from 5.4.0-29 to 5.4.0-31

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

There was a recent kernel update to 5.4.0-31 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and this package has been installed. However, livepatch does not recognize this, and instead says that 5.4.0-29 is ok, and no patches to apply (see screenshot).

[image]

In the screenshot I show apt-policy for linux-headers-generic - the same is true for linux-image-generic and linux-generic - all are version 5.4.0-31.

I had the impression that livepatch would do this upgrade, so I don't have to reboot the machine. Am I wrong about this, and is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Ok, I can see that some kernel updates still require reboot. I had the impression that all kernel updates would be livepatched, but I reckon that isn't the case. Thanks.